# Memory shortage when using MICE in R

Tags: r, r-mice

I'm trying to create multiple imputations in R with the MICE package but kepp running out of memory. 
This is the error message I get:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 219 Kb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unlist(vlist, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 6500Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In unlist(vlist, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 6500Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I use 64 bit R and windows 7 and 8 Gb ram. I've tried increase the fysical memory and the memory size R is allowed to use to 8 Gb and 6.5 Gb respectively but it still does not work. Currently I'm trying to do the imputations on a data set contining 27 000 rows and 17 columns, but i would want use on a bigger data with 1 600 000 rows and 17 columns.

Can someone help me? Would deeply appreciate it.

/Jesper

Comment: last time I tried, imputation is memory intensive. Can you try on smaller data? you can also track memory usage from task manager and check how it increases over time.

Comment: U can use packages like `ff` and `snow`. To decrease memory use. Or try to use packages for parallel programming in R. Which enables you to use multiple cores. Default of R is using 1 core.

Comment: I reduced the number of predictors and columns in the data frame which made i work on a big enough data set. Maybe i'll try the ff package though. Thank you very much!! R-users are always so helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

To check the current limit of memory (in Mb) try

```
memory.limit(size = NA)
```

To maximize it (with respect to your 8Gb RAM) try

```
memory.limit(size = 8190)
```

Also, don't forget to call `gc()` a couple of times before running any memory intensive function. If it still does not work, make sure to close any other active applications, restart R and perform the above. If this does not fix your problem, try exploiting the functionality of other packages like `ff`, `snow`, and `bigmemory`.