# Understanding memory use in R: "cannot allocate vector of size"

Tags: r, memory-management, out-of-memory, r-mice

I have read about other people's problems with memory use, but none of them help with the following issue. I have a 64 bit R environment with 16GB of RAM.

Import .gz file of size 229MB. (the unzipped version is 921MB)

```
accepted_def <- read.csv(gzfile('accepted_2007_to_2017.csv.gz'), 
na.strings='')
acc_dt <- as.data.table(accepted_def)
```

By this time, my R Studio R session memory use has gone from about 100MB to 3GB

Clean up data and get rid of unnecessary features:

```
library(dplyr)
df.train <- select(acc_dt, 
-1,-2,-10,-11,-16,-19,-21,-22,-23,-26,-46,-48,-49)
```

Finally, attempt to impute missing values with MICE:

```
library(mice)
df.new = as.data.frame(mice(df.train, m=1, method = 'cart', printFlag=F))
```

Now, my R session memory use jumps to over 12GB and I get the following:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.6 Mb
```

Any ideas on what is going on would be appreciated!

Comment: This error is throws when R has not enough memory to continue is operation. Your data seems to take all your available memory. From your code, in your workspace you have `accepted_def`, `acc_dt` and `df_train` which should take around 3 Go probably. Then, `mice` probably create copies of your table for its operations (hence the 12Gb), and probably wants more space that you have no more.

Comment: You have to clean your workspace to make as more space as possible and reduce the size of your `df.train`. Seems to have worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231371/memory-shortage-when-using-mice-in-r)

Comment: Thanks guys. I have cleaned my workspace and I thought about splitting my data in smaller sets. However, there are lots of missing values in some of the variables and I didn't want to mess up their imputation (correlations with other variables) by splitting the set.

Comment: I haven't really used `mice` but it looks like you're trying to impute values column-wise. In this case, you might consider reading each column independently, impute values, then write output to file, and clean up environment. Repeat for all columns.

Comment: 1) try removing the call to `as.data.frame` and just save the mice output to an object. Nesting calls can be problematic when memory is an issue. 2) Keep your workspace clean and avoid unnecessary copies of large data. 3) Try reducing the complexity of the imputation model. The function has two arguments for that (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf) and allows passing other arguments to `rpart.control` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/rpart.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Simon, that's very helpful. I had already given up, but I will explore these options, especially the integration with rpart.